# If we sign up to Alexa Pro, will others know it?

Tags: alexa

I just signed up for [Alexa Pro](http://www.alexa.com/pro/subscription).

If people go to `mydomainname.com`, will they know that whether or not the domain is registered in Alexa Pro?

Comment: Why would it matter if they could or not? Alexa is not used in rankings. Also, you should be able to do this test yourselve by logging out of Alexa and seeing if your page says PRO on it, additionally if your a paying customer Alexa should be able to answer this type of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on their [plans and pricing](http://www.alexa.com/pro/subscription) page, the benefits that you get are information and statistics about your website.  There doesn't appear to be anything such as site badges that would let visitors to your site know that you have signed up for the pro service.

I also cannot find a page where Alexa publishes a list of their Alexa Pro customers.

You could let your visitors know that you use Alexa Pro, but other than that there doesn't appear to be an easy way for them to find out.